# Merge Sort code is not working and showing exception

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

```
public static void Merge(int[] arr,int p,int q,int r ) 
{
    int n1 = q-p;
    int n2 = r-q;
    int[] L=new int[n1];
    int[] R = new int[r-n2];

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[i];

    foreach (int x in L)
        Console.WriteLine(x);

    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
        R[i] = arr[q+i];

    Console.WriteLine("New part");

    foreach (int x in R)
        Console.WriteLine(x);

    int k=0, d=0;

    for (int i = p; i < r; i++)
    {
        if (L[k] <= R[k])
        {
            arr[i] = L[k];
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[i] = R[d];
            d++;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code shows `exception(index out of bound when I call from main() method using Merge(arr,0,0,12)`. Where arr is an int array of length 12.

Comment: Please add stack trace, and the code you used to invoke the method from Main().

Comment: Seriously, how can a question that does not contain nearly enough information to solve it and even lacks a question mark receive multiple upvotes?

Comment: @Heuster I was wondering the exact same thing. I'm seeing alot of upvotes on very badly formulated question tonight

Comment: Please name the variables properly. p,q,r are not meaningful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an Index out of bounds exception in this part:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
R[i] = arr[q+i];
```

Your R-array is of size 0, while n2 is defined as 12 with the given arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You array L is declared of size q-p, which are both 0

Comment: Thanks. I used Merge(arr,0,6,12) but the same problem prevails. :(

Answer (score 1):

Both you L and R array are defined as too small

Initialize them like this instead:

```
int[] L = new int[arr.Length];
int[] R = new int[arr.Length];
```